# Get Data from Jquery Template

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-templates

Hi All i have built an text editor to help me learn more about javascript and jquery, i am trying to add a ajax image uploader, the uploader uses a jquery template, i have added the following to the table row

```
<td><a href="#" class="addToEditor"  data-id="{%=file.name%}" >Add To Editor</a></td>
```

how do i get the data-id value out of the template. i want it return the true value not %=file.name%

when using a on click in jquery i can not get it to return anything alert

here is the full template

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="addToEditor"  data-id="{%=file.name%}" >Add To Editor</a></td>
    </tr>

{% } %}
   </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Show us the on click event.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".addToEditor").click(function() {
   var x = ($(this).data("id"));
   alert(x);
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Is your first snippet of code appearing in your DOM? (in your html document as is ?) - Are you sure you compile the template?

Comment: it is appearing as the template

Comment: Ok. So how do you append the data to the DOM? Something like `$("#template-download").tmpl(data).appendTo("body");` ? Try this tutorial: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx